# Preg Match All into single variables

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

im really stuck in my code.

I have a text thats looks like this

> [[QVQ]]Money [[QVQ]]New Zealand | WATER [ 2nd Test ] [[QVQ]]Who? (Personality 
>       Test) [[QVQ]] New Car

And I need the text behind the **[[QVQ]]**. I read about preg match.

```
preg_match_all('/\[[QVQ\]](.*?)\[[QVQ\]]/s', $input, $matches);
```

But how do I use preg_match in this case to get the matches into single Variables?

Like $match1 , $match2 ,$match3 [...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `[` and `]` needs the be escaped, without escaping those you make a character class which is a list of allowed characters, or a range (0-9, would be any single number). You can read more here, http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.

Code:

```
preg_match_all('/\[\[QVQ\]\](.*?)\[\[QVQ\]\]/s', '[[QVQ]]Money [[QVQ]]New Zealand | WATER [ 2nd Test ] [[QVQ]]Who? (Personality 
Test) [[QVQ]] New Car', $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/826134
Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nHELMW/1/

`$matches[1]` will be an array of all found terms.

**Update:**

Since what you actually have is the `[[QVQ]]` as a marker you should just use `preg_split`.

```
$matches = preg_split('/\[\[QVQ\]\]/', '[[QVQ]]Money [[QVQ]]New Zealand | WATER [ 2nd Test ] [[QVQ]]Who? (Personality Test) [[QVQ]] New Car', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

`$matches` will then be an array with all your matches.

Demo: https://eval.in/826151

Comment: Thank you very much! But "New Zealand | WATER [ 2nd Test ]" is missing in this example :(

Comment: [[QVQ]] Is starting delimiter, and a new [[QVQ]] is an other starting delimiter so its also an ending deliminter, Basicly I want the texts behind each of the starting delimiter's

Comment: Both seem working I think but I struggle to find a way too make it work with $matches[1] like you did before, so I can use the variable again

Answer (score 0):

Because chris isn't using look arounds with his `preg_match_all()` pattern, not all substrings are captured.

This will capture all of the substrings (without any unwanted leading/trailing white space characters) using `preg_match_all()`: `/(?<=\]{2}) ?\K.+?(?=$| \[{2})/` [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nHELMW/2)

```
var_export(preg_match_all('/(?<=\]{2}) ?\K.+?(?=$| \[{2})/', $input, $out) ? $out[0] : []);
```

---

chris' `preg_split()` method does not contend with leading and trailing spaces.  This is a corrected/refined method (this is my recommended regex method):

```
var_export(preg_split('/ ?\[{2}QVQ\]{2} ?/', $input, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

---

This is a non-regex method:

```
var_export(array_values(array_filter(array_map('trim', explode('[[QVQ]]', $input)), 'strlen')));
```

Breakdown of non-regex method:

```
array_values(                          // reindex the array
    array_filter(                      // unset any empty elements 
        array_map('trim',              // remove leading/trailing spaces from each element
            explode('[[QVQ]]', $input) // split on known delimiter
        ),
        'strlen'
     )
 )
```